# Fly command won't work after installing flight plan

Tags: node.js, npm, rsync

So I was working through a tutorial to deploy my node app to a server. They had me npm install flightplan -g so I can use the 'fly' command. This all worked but for the fly command to work I needed to install rsync. I finally got rsync to work after changing my PATH. But now when I use to fly command I get "'fly' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I've tried changing the PATH hundreds of times to different things and I can't for the life of my get the fly command to work again. I've tried reinstalling flightplan globally a bunch of times. NOTHING IS WORKING.

Comment: did you try the command to run the command in a new terminal?

Answer (score 1):

[Node JS NPM modules installed but command not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710550/node-js-npm-modules-installed-but-command-not-recognized?rq=1)

This was the answer I was looking for.. I had the end of my path set to npm/fly and not just npm....