# clasp is not recognized after installing on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10, npm-install, clasp

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code as Google Sheets Script editor on a win 10 machine.

To make a long story short I will not describe all my steps, as I didn't really understood at the beginning exactly what I need. I also wouldn't be able to do it even I want to.

The current situation is that clasp is not recognized on the system.
These are command line results:

```
c:\>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

c:\>where clasp
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\clasp
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\clasp.cmd
```

on drive c: root (and any folder other than  `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\clasp`) clasp is not recognized

```
c:\>clasp -v     
'clasp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.


C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm>clasp -v
2.3.0
```

One suggestion I found is setting Windows user variable as follows:

```
SET NODE_PATH=% APPDATA%\npm
```

Didn't help.

npm related paths on Windows `PATH` :

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I tried to add to `PATH` the following file path **before** the one above

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
```

Didn't help

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168581/6202910) looks like npm is actually installed twice. For current user `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm` and for all users `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm`.
Maybe this is the problem.

I would like to start over from clean env.

How can I uninstall the local user npm installation on `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add path to npm in environment variables. Then it will work.

- Press Ctrl+r
- Write `%AppData%`  and hit enter
- You will land on roaming folder
- Go to `npm` folder inside `roaming` and check if a file named `clasp` is there or not
- If yes, then add the path to `npm` in environment variables
- In my case the path is `C:\Users\HARI\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: I did exactly as you said and I can see casp installed in my user npm folder but the trick with the env variable does not work for me, I also tried https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/705