# 'clinic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, profiling, node-modules

I tried following the documentation for Clinic.js https://clinicjs.org/documentation/

First i installed clinic globally as instructed
`npm install -g clinic`

When installing this appeared

```bash
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\clinic -> C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\clinic\bin.js
+ clinic@9.0.0
updated 3 packages in 210.329s
```

After that when I try running the command `clinic --help` I get the error `'clinic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

my node version is `v14.15.1`.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what happens when you run the install?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't have my global packages directory added to my PATH. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710550/node-js-npm-modules-installed-but-command-not-recognized) answered my issue.

First I ran the command `npm get prefix` to get the global packages directory path. The path appeared to be `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm` .

Then I went to **Edit the sysem environment variables** using the Windows search. Clicked on **Environment Variables...** on bottom right. Double clicked **Path** from **User variables** section. Added `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm` as a new path and clicked Ok.

Restarted my IDE and ran `clinic --help` and got the response `Clinic - v9.0.0`