# Why am I getting syntax error while installing NPM?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm-install, command-prompt

I have installed NodeJS v17.5.0 but when I am trying to install angular/cli using npm syntax in command prompt it is showing error

> C:\Users\bjnai>npm install -g @angular/cli

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> /F was unexpected at this time.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu9jJ.png)

Comment: is this related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30710550/3462319

Comment: No, I have tried that method still its not working

Comment: Did you find any solution for it @ProjectAndroid

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Next time better just paste errors here, so we can copy them.

Comment: Still it is showing same error