# Can't use openai in command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, command-line, openai-api

I know this is a super basic question but pls help me with this problemI have properly installed the openai with the nodejs library using npm install openai [openai docs](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) and updated them but when working on fine tuning my model it throws an error openai is not recognized as as internal or external command operable program or batch file and is installed at this location C:\Users\Desktop\openaimodel\node_modules\openai [image: openai location]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS NPM modules installed but command not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710550/node-js-npm-modules-installed-but-command-not-recognized)

Comment: You said you did `npm install openai` but you linked to docs that only include how to install with python, `pip install --upgrade openai`

Answer (score 2):

For Python developers If openai command not found in Windows command prompt add this path to your Path variable in Environment Variables :

```
C:\Users\{YourUsername}\appdata\roaming\python\python{-PythonVersion}\Scripts
```

Replace the {YourUsername} with your Windows username and the {-PythonVersion} with your current Python version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do `npm install -g openai`, the `-g` option is very important: It installs it globally, which should create for you the `openai` command.