Upgrading Angular-CLI from Angular 17 to Angular 19 causing major errors on my system -
I was running nG version 17.3 on my Win10 system. I wanted to upgrade my Angular CLI to latest version 19.
So I did the following steps-


npm uninstall -g @angular/cli



npm install -g @angular/cli@latest



Now, if I try to run ng version on my command prompt, it gives the following message
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My whole system is screwed up. How do I get Angular up and running again with the latest CLI installed?

Maybe your global npm packages aren't working in general, are you able to install other npm packages globally? For example, check if this question helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30710550/5470544

I have edited your question and removed the parts pointing out the urgency of the issue. This will not give you any faster results, it tends to have the opposite effect. Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/5470544

Ok, @JSONDerulo thanks.

Did the linked question solve your issue? If yes, I can mark this question as a duplicate, to help future readers.

Hi @JSONDerulo I have finally got this working. The steps I followed were -

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli/@latest

Now if I run ng version from comm. prompt, it shows the installed version as 19. I checked the environment variables to make sure the path is present there. It is. I have VS CODE installed on my system. I tried running some ng commands from the integrated terminal of that too. They are working, much to my relief.

Currently enrolled in Angular bootcamp, had same Issues few days back
first Check Node.jsand npm Versions-
Run node -v and npm -v to ensure you have compatible versions installed.
Add npm to PATH:
Open the System Properties window.
Click the "Advanced" tab.
Click "Environment Variables."
Edit the "Path" variable under "System variables" to include the npm global installation path (usually C:\Users<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm).
Restart your command prompt.
Reinstall Angular CLI:
Run npm install -g @angular/cli@latest in an administrator command prompt.
I prefer removing -g if you want to use different angular versions for different projects because they may collide. This is my hypothesis.
Verify Installation:
Run ng v to check if Angular CLI is recognized.
Try restarting Your PC
These Angular developers push new versions every 6 months hard to cope up with deprecated properties.
